# Does file(GLOB ...) search directory on every cmake invocation?

Tags: cmake

When `file(GLOB ...)` is called, CMake applies regex to all files it can find. The question is whether it's done only on first `cmake` invocation, or every time?

In other words, does use of `file(GLOB ...)` slows down Makefiles regenration process? The same question can be applied to `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done every time (the results might be different, naturally).

Don't worry about it slowing you down.  Build systems have to do a `stat` (or equivalent) on tens, hundreds, or thousands of files every invocation and a glob or two won't even show up as a blip.

Comment: Still, can't it be optimized if CMake would remember directory's last change time and compare it on next run?

Comment: @arrowdodger: That would require a complicated caching mechanism.  The operating system already caches directory entries, so the IO time during a second invocation is minimal.  You'd be throwing hours of work after a couple milliseconds of speedup at best.

Comment: "It's done every time" is not the entire story. When the `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the `file(GLOB ..)` statement has not changed, it is likely that `cmake` will **not** rerun the file, and _a fortiori_ will not rerun the globbing. For a discussion of this problem, see [a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/cmake-file-glob-is-not-evil) I just opened.